# Использование TinyMCE к созданому через DOM объекту

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tinymce

Здравствуйте! Имеется такая задача: на странице используется редактор текста TinyMCE, для добавления описаний к слайдам, и имеется кнопочка 'добавить слайд', по нажатию которой добавляется textarea, но добавляется "чистый textarea", без пименения к нему tinymce.
(так же в проекте используется фреймворк UIKit 2.x)

Мой код формы слайдов:

```html
       <form class="uk-form uk-grid uk-margin-bottom" id="theForm" method="post" action="">
  <div class="uk-width-1-2">
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <label class="uk-form-label" for="title">Наименование</label>
      <input class="uk-form-expand" type="text" name="title"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <label class="uk-form-label" for="title">Тип</label>
      <input class="uk-form-expand" type="text" name="title"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <label class="uk-form-label" for="title">Габартиные размеры</label>
      <input class="uk-form-expand" type="text" name="title"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <label class="uk-form-label" for="title">Входное напряжение (V)</label>
      <input class="uk-form-expand" type="text" name="title"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <label class="uk-form-label" for="title">К-во подклчаемых DC</label>
      <input class="uk-form-expand" type="text" name="title"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <label class="uk-form-label" for="title">Ток макс. на один мотор</label>
      <input class="uk-form-expand" type="text" name="title"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <label class="uk-form-label" for="title">Подключаемых ЭМП датчиков (шт)</label>
      <input class="uk-form-expand" type="text" name="title"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <label class="uk-form-label" for="title">Интерфейс связи с ПК</label>
      <input class="uk-form-expand" type="text" name="title"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <label class="uk-form-label" for="title">Микроконтроллер</label>
      <input class="uk-form-expand" type="text" name="title"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <label class="uk-form-label" for="title">Частота кварца</label>
      <input class="uk-form-expand" type="text" name="title"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <label class="uk-form-label" for="title">Входы АЦП (шт)</label>
      <input class="uk-form-expand" type="text" name="title"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <label class="uk-form-label" for="title">Документация</label>
      <input class="uk-form-expand" type="text" name="title"></input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="uk-width-1-2">
    <h3 class="uk-text-center">Добавить фотографии</h3>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <div id="targetElement0" ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="slides">
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-margin-top uk-margin-top uk-width-1-1 uk-grid">
    <h3 class="uk-width-1-1 uk-text-center">Добавить слайды</h3>
    <div class="uk-width-1-2">
      <div id="image-preview">
        <label for="image-upload" id="image-label">Выберите файл</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image-upload"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-1-2">
      <div class="uk-form-row">
        <center><h2>Особенности</h2></center>
      </div>
      <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
        <textarea>Next, start a free trial!</textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-margin-top uk-margin-top uk-width-1-1 uk-grid">
    <h3 class="uk-width-1-1 uk-text-center">Слайд №2</h3>
    <div class="uk-width-1-2">
      <div id="image-preview">
        <label for="image-upload2" id="image-label2">Выберите файл</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image-upload2"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-1-2">
      <div class="uk-form-row">
        <center><h2>Особенности</h2></center>
      </div>
      <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
        <textarea>Next, start a free trial!</textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-margin-top uk-margin-top uk-width-1-1 uk-grid">
    <h3 class="uk-width-1-1 uk-text-center">Слайд №3</h3>
    <div class="uk-width-1-2">
      <div id="image-preview">
        <label for="image-upload3" id="image-label3">Выберите файл</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image-upload3"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-1-2">
      <div class="uk-form-row">
        <center><h2>Особенности</h2></center>
      </div>
      <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
        <textarea>Next, start a free trial!</textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="uk-form-row uk-width-1-2 uk-align-center">
    <button class="uk-button uk-width-expand" onclick="addslideformrow()" type="button" id="butt">Добавить ещё один слайд</button>
  </div>
       </form>
```

Мой код кнопки:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
      var i = 4;
      function addslideformrow() {
      var parent = document.getElementById('slides');
      var container = document.createElement('div');
      
      container.innerHTML = '<div class="uk-form-row uk-margin-top uk-margin-top uk-width-1-1 uk-grid">' + 
 '<h3 class="uk-width-1-1 uk-text-center">Слайд №'+i+'</h3>'+ 
 '<div class="uk-width-1-2">'+
   '<div id="image-preview">'+
     '<label for="image-upload'+i+'" id="image-label'+i+'">Выберите файл</label>'+ 
     '<input type="file" name="image" id="image-upload'+i+'"/>'+ 
     '</div>'+ 
   '</div>'+ 
 '<div class="uk-width-1-2">'+ 
   '<div class="uk-form-row">'+
     '<center><h2>Особенности</h2></center>'+ 
     '</div>'+ 
   '<div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">'+ 
     '<textarea>Next, start a free trial!</textarea>'+ 
     '</div>'+ 
   '</div>'+  
 '</div>';
      
       if (++i <= 11) {
    parent.appendChild(container);
    }
      };
    </script>
```

(количество слайдов ограничено 10-ю)

[image: Скриншот]

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы при добавлении нового элемента в DOM, он становился редактором TinyMCE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы просто после добавления новых элементов не инициализировали `tinymece`.

```
tinymce.init({ 
    selector:'.editor'
});
```

Вот рабочий вариант вашего кода. Инициализация для `textarea` с классом `editor`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.6.4/tinymce.min.js"></script>


<form class="uk-form uk-grid uk-margin-bottom" id="theForm" method="post" action="">
  <div class="uk-width-1-2">
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <label class="uk-form-label" for="title">Наименование</label>
      <input class="uk-form-expand" type="text" name="title"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <label class="uk-form-label" for="title">Тип</label>
      <input class="uk-form-expand" type="text" name="title"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <label class="uk-form-label" for="title">Габартиные размеры</label>
      <input class="uk-form-expand" type="text" name="title"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <label class="uk-form-label" for="title">Входное напряжение (V)</label>
      <input class="uk-form-expand" type="text" name="title"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <label class="uk-form-label" for="title">К-во подклчаемых DC</label>
      <input class="uk-form-expand" type="text" name="title"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <label class="uk-form-label" for="title">Ток макс. на один мотор</label>
      <input class="uk-form-expand" type="text" name="title"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <label class="uk-form-label" for="title">Подключаемых ЭМП датчиков (шт)</label>
      <input class="uk-form-expand" type="text" name="title"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <label class="uk-form-label" for="title">Интерфейс связи с ПК</label>
      <input class="uk-form-expand" type="text" name="title"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <label class="uk-form-label" for="title">Микроконтроллер</label>
      <input class="uk-form-expand" type="text" name="title"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <label class="uk-form-label" for="title">Частота кварца</label>
      <input class="uk-form-expand" type="text" name="title"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <label class="uk-form-label" for="title">Входы АЦП (шт)</label>
      <input class="uk-form-expand" type="text" name="title"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <label class="uk-form-label" for="title">Документация</label>
      <input class="uk-form-expand" type="text" name="title"></input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="uk-width-1-2">
    <h3 class="uk-text-center">Добавить фотографии</h3>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
      <div id="targetElement0"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="slides">
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-margin-top uk-margin-top uk-width-1-1 uk-grid">
      <h3 class="uk-width-1-1 uk-text-center">Добавить слайды</h3>
      <div class="uk-width-1-2">
        <div id="image-preview">
          <label for="image-upload" id="image-label">Выберите файл</label>
          <input type="file" name="image" id="image-upload" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="uk-width-1-2">
        <div class="uk-form-row">
          <center>
            <h2>Особенности</h2>
          </center>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
          <textarea>Next, start a free trial!</textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-margin-top uk-margin-top uk-width-1-1 uk-grid">
      <h3 class="uk-width-1-1 uk-text-center">Слайд №2</h3>
      <div class="uk-width-1-2">
        <div id="image-preview">
          <label for="image-upload2" id="image-label2">Выберите файл</label>
          <input type="file" name="image" id="image-upload2" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="uk-width-1-2">
        <div class="uk-form-row">
          <center>
            <h2>Особенности</h2>
          </center>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
          <textarea>Next, start a free trial!</textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row uk-margin-top uk-margin-top uk-width-1-1 uk-grid">
      <h3 class="uk-width-1-1 uk-text-center">Слайд №3</h3>
      <div class="uk-width-1-2">
        <div id="image-preview">
          <label for="image-upload3" id="image-label3">Выберите файл</label>
          <input type="file" name="image" id="image-upload3" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="uk-width-1-2">
        <div class="uk-form-row">
          <center>
            <h2>Особенности</h2>
          </center>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">
          <textarea>Next, start a free trial!</textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="uk-form-row uk-width-1-2 uk-align-center">
    <button class="uk-button uk-width-expand" onclick="addslideformrow()" type="button" id="butt">Добавить ещё один слайд</button>
  </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i = 4;

  function addslideformrow() {
    var parent = document.getElementById('slides');
    var container = document.createElement('div');

    container.innerHTML = '<div class="uk-form-row uk-margin-top uk-margin-top uk-width-1-1 uk-grid">' +
      '<h3 class="uk-width-1-1 uk-text-center">Слайд №' + i + '</h3>' +
      '<div class="uk-width-1-2">' +
      '<div id="image-preview">' +
      '<label for="image-upload' + i + '" id="image-label' + i + '">Выберите файл</label>' +
      '<input type="file" name="image" id="image-upload' + i + '"/>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="uk-width-1-2">' +
      '<div class="uk-form-row">' +
      '<center><h2>Особенности</h2></center>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="uk-form-row uk-form-horizontal">' +
      '<textarea class="editor">Next, start a free trial!</textarea>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>';

    if (++i <= 11) {
      parent.appendChild(container);
    }    
  tinymce.init({ 
  selector:'.editor'
    });
    
  };
  addslideformrow();
  });
</script>
```